# Copy range to clipboard as separate values

Tags: excel, clipboard

I would like to copy some range of data, but retrieve them one by one. Ex:

I got A1:C3 range = 9 cells and I want to copy them with one move and than be able to use them one by one. Tries to find it in excel, ditto and art clip - nothing.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Welcom to SO. Just curious, but why you would want this? Not sure if possible, to be honest.

Comment: This sounds like an [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem). Why do you need to copy them at all?  Why not just use the `INDEX` function to retrieve the individual values?

Comment: " copy them with one move and than be able to use them one by one. " >> isn't "use them one by one. " contains multiple steps? d u mean use it in excel or other place?

Comment: I found a way using simple JS code via Automator to fill forms one by one (still can't fill 1000 at once coz of gov restrictions). Sorry for trivial question :) Still im wondering if there is any clipboard manager for doing so. Like when I got my personal data saved and I can fill any Sign in form with them, but cannot alter them quickly.